# Type error relating to Word8 and Int

Tags: haskell

Trying to convert a bytestring to a hex ascii string display

```
wordtoascii :: Int -> String
wordtoascii y =
  showIntAtBase 16 intToDigit ( fromEnum  y) ""

bs2string :: Data.ByteString.ByteString -> String
bs2string bs = do
  Prelude.map( wordtoascii,
               (unpack bs))
```

Type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a -> b'
       against inferred type `(Int -> String, [GHC.Word.Word8])'
In the first argument of `Prelude.map', namely
    `(wordtoascii, (unpack bs))'
In the expression: Prelude.map (wordtoascii, (unpack bs))
In the expression: do { Prelude.map (wordtoascii, (unpack bs)) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the syntax for what you think it is.

```
Prelude.map( wordtoascii,
            (unpack bs))
```

That is the same as:

```
let x = (wordtoascii, unpack bs)
in map x
```

Remove the parentheses and the comma.

```
map wordtoascii (unpack bs)
```

However, this is also wrong.  Because the type of the above expression is `[String]`, not `String`.  You want `concatMap`, which is like `map` but splices the results together in one string.

```
concatMap wordtoascii (unpack bs)
```

Or, even better,

```
bs2string = concatMap wordtoascii . unpack
```

The comma is for creating tuples, lists, and records.  For example, `(1, 7) :: (Int, Int)` could be cartesian coordinates.  The comma does not appear in function calls.

Typically, `ByteString` is imported only as a qualified import, since so many functions clash with `Prelude`.  This eliminates the need for `Prelude.` qualification on the functions that do clash.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as S
bs2string = map wordtoascii . S.unpack
```

The `S` stands for `Strict`.  `BS` is also a common choice, it stands for for Bytestring (Strict).

Comment: Interesting... After I fix that, I still get a conversion error as "Couldn't match - Expected Int against intferred type GHC.Word.Word8".

Comment: Well, then use `(wordtoascii . fromIntegral)` instead of `wordtoascii`.  The `fromIntegral` function is very, very handy.  It is also quite well optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Dietrich explained the main problem with your code. However, there is also the issue that `unpack` returns a list of `Word8` and your code expects `Int`. This can be fixed by simply relaxing the type signature of `wordtoascii`:

```
> let wordtoascii y = showIntAtBase 16 intToDigit ( fromEnum  y) ""
> :t wordtoascii
wordtoascii :: Enum a => a -> String
```

`Word8` is an instance of `Enum`, so with this type signature you can use it directly.